# 2008R2 Standard VM on Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

Licensing aside, can a 2008R2 VM on a 2012 Standard Hyper-V host use more than 32GB of RAM? Is this restriction built into the OS or does it look at a lower more hardware related level. (i.e. therefore a VM wouldn't be affected?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an OS limit. Windows 2008 R2 64 bit has a memory maximum of 32GB, whether it is a physical machine, or VM.

See this link for all Windows memory limits.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008_r2